# Sequence of functions that converges uniformly in $R$, derivatives does not converge punctually at any point of $R$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I've not been able to give a example of a sequence of functions that converges uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$ such that the sequence of the derivatives does not converge punctually in any point of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Something like $(1/\sqrt n)\sin(nx)$.

Comment: Consider infinitely many upper semicircles of radius $1$, joint together at their endpoints, like the letter "m". Let this be the graph of $f_1$. Now draw a similar graph, but make the radii $1/2$ instead of $1$. This will be the graph of $f_2$. Go on like this. These functions will converge uniformly to $f =0$.

Comment: I second portakal's notion, and recall a particular example that I saw while perusing the forum a few months back

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227191/uniform-convergence-and-lengths